# How to find if f(x) has a minimum or maximum over an interval

Tags: calculus, optimization

If f(x) is continuous over [-1,6], and f(-1)=-7 and f(4) =-14, then how do you find if there's a minimum or maximum in (-1,6)

Answer (score 0):

You calculate $f'(x)$ and check if it vanishes in $[-1,6]$. In that case, you check if it's a minimum or a maximum and confront it with the values you already have.

Comment: I'm not sure how to calculate the derivative in this question. f(x) is not explicitly stated; the question only said it was continuous. If you could clear that up, it would be great.

Comment: If you haven't any other hypothesis about your function, then, as @gt6989b correctly points out, there's no way to find maxima or minima of $f$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Perhaps I'm missing something in the problem, but it really didn't show any more details :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to do this without any further information, I don't think it's possible. You can have a parabola with a vertex at $x=0$ passing through both of your points, opening up or down, or $f$ may be a line -- so minimum, maximum and neither are all possible.

However, if you are asking how to find it using other information, since you cannot assume $f$ is differentiable (as you wrote $f$ is only continuous), I would sample a bunch of points in the middle trying to see if you can get $f(x) < -14$ (which would imply a relative extremum in $(x,4)$) or $f(x) > -7$ (which would imply a relative extremum in $(-1,x)$), and then use the [bisection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) to find the root numerically.

If you can assume $f$ is differentiable and you can solve $f'(x)=0$, that would give you the candidate points.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and see if it works.